# Copy Legend of Chart to Powerpoint with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, graph, powerpoint, legend

I work on an excel script that creates powerpoint slides.
On a powerpoint slide, I want to show the legend of a chart, but not the rest of the chart.

Here is an excerpt of my code:

```
With Sheets("data")
    Set bereich = Range(.Cells(Daty + 1, 3), .Cells(Daty + 2 + UBound(SubCategories), Datx + UBound(anzahl, 1)))
    Set dia = .ChartObjects.Add(10, 800, 650, 400)
   .ChartObjects(dia.Name).Activate
   dia.Name = "ideaspersubcatstatus"       
   .Shapes(dia.Name).Left = Range(.Cells(intSubCat + 3, 1), .Cells(intSubCat + 3, 1)).Left
   .Shapes(dia.Name).Top = Range(.Cells(intSubCat + 3, 1), .Cells(intSubCat + 3, 1)).Top
End With
With ActiveChart
    .ChartType = xlBarStacked
    .SetSourceData Source:=bereich, PlotBy:=xlColumns
    .HasLegend = True
    .PlotArea.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabelSpacing = 1
    .ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = 0
    .Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Border.LineStyle = xlDot
End With
```

I either need to copy the legend of the graph to powerpoint, or remove everything but the legend from the chart before I copy it to Powerpoint.

```
    With .Slides(9)
        'copy graph from Excel
        Workbooks("data.xls").Worksheets("data").ChartObjects("ideaspersubcatstatus").Copy
        'paste graph into Powerpoint
        .Shapes.Paste        
    End With
```

".PlotArea.Delete" is not supported. ".ChartObjects(1).Legend.Copy" did not work, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can copy only the legend, or delete the plot area -- or delete all of its contents (series) without the legend disappearing.

What you can do is make the plot area really small, and hide it behind the legend:

```
With ActiveChart
    .Axes(xlCategory).Delete
    .Axes(xlValue).Delete
    .PlotArea.ClearFormats
    .Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Delete
    ' Make it small
    With .PlotArea
        .Width = 0
        .Height = 0
    End With
    ' Move the legend on top of it
    With .Legend
        .Left = 1
        .Top = 1
    End With
End With
```

If you want, you can then reduce the size of your Chart area so that it fits snuggly around the legend.